# How to group objects in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
WalletCreditNoteVO a1 = new WalletCreditNoteVO(1L, 1L, "A", WalletCreditNoteStatus.EXPIRED, null, null, CreditNoteType.CAMPAIGN_VOUCHER, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE, "GBP");
WalletCreditNoteVO a2 = new WalletCreditNoteVO(1L, 1L, "A", WalletCreditNoteStatus.EXPIRED, null, null, CreditNoteType.CAMPAIGN_VOUCHER, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.TEN, "GBP");
WalletCreditNoteVO a3 = new WalletCreditNoteVO(2L, 1L, "A", WalletCreditNoteStatus.EXPIRED, null, null, CreditNoteType.CAMPAIGN_VOUCHER, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE, "GBP");
WalletCreditNoteVO a4 = new WalletCreditNoteVO(2L, 1L, "A", WalletCreditNoteStatus.EXPIRED, null, null, CreditNoteType.CAMPAIGN_VOUCHER, BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.TEN, "GBP");

final List<WalletCreditNoteVO> walletCreditNoteVOs = Lists.newArrayList(a1, a2, a3, a4);


Map<WalletCreditNoteVO, BigDecimal> collect2 = walletCreditNoteVOs.stream().collect(
        groupingBy(wr -> new WalletCreditNoteVO(wr.getCreditNoteId(), wr.getWalletCustomerId(), wr.getCreditNoteTitle(),
                        wr.getWalletCreditNoteStatus(), wr.getCreditNoteStartDate(), wr.getCreditNoteExpiryDate(), wr.getCreditNoteType(), wr.getCreditNoteValue(), wr.getCurrency()),
                mapping(WalletCreditNoteVO::getAvailableBalance,
                        reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, (sum, elem) -> sum.add(elem)))));
```

I want to introduce condition for final reducing to be either sum (as written above) or last value in the list of BigDecimal based on the status of getWalletCreditNoteStatus

Can someone please help.

---

Thanks @xiumeteo . Below is improved solution

```
Function<WalletCreditNoteVO, WalletCreditNoteVO> function = wr -> new WalletCreditNoteVO(wr.getCreditNoteId(), wr.getWalletCustomerId(), wr.getCreditNoteTitle(),
        wr.getWalletCreditNoteStatus(), wr.getCreditNoteStartDate(), wr.getCreditNoteExpiryDate(), wr.getCreditNoteType(), wr.getCreditNoteValue(), wr.getCurrency());

final Map<WalletCreditNoteVO, BigDecimal> collectMap =
        walletCreditNoteVOs.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(function, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        toList(),
                        (list) -> {
                            final List<BigDecimal> availableBalances = list.stream().map(WalletCreditNoteVO::getAvailableBalance).collect(toList());
                            if (list.stream().allMatch(WalletCreditNoteVO::isStatusExpired)) {
                                return availableBalances.stream().filter(o -> o != null).reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null).abs();
                            } else {
                                return availableBalances.stream().filter(o -> o != null).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
                            }
                        })));

List<WalletCreditNoteVO> walletCreditNoteVOGrouped = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<WalletCreditNoteVO, BigDecimal> entry : collectMap.entrySet()){
    WalletCreditNoteVO key = entry.getKey();
    key.setAvailableBalance(entry.getValue());
    walletCreditNoteVOGrouped.add(key);
}
```

I now want to remove 'for loop' and stream logic should just give me one list of WalletCreditNoteVO instead of Map of WalletCreditNoteVO as key and  BigDecimal as value, with value set directly in the WalletCreditNoteVO

Thanks all again (I can't add code in my comments so adding it here).

Comment: instead of  (sum, elem) -> sum.add(elem) just  (sum, elem) -> elem will give me last element. Now how to make these two operations conditional based on value of getWalletCreditNoteStatus.

Comment: Do you actually need to group objects by making more objects via constructor? If equals is defined by what's in the constructor, you can just use `i -> i` lambda or `java.util.function.Function.identity()`. Now, to make them conditional, you have to roll your own collector instead of the `mapping` one - the collector which will make the decision which function to use for collecting the data.

Comment: How the equals and hashcode of `WalletCreditNoteVO` is defined?

Comment: And furthermore, even if you did need to copy them, you should create a copy constructor that just takes a single object as a parameter and copies all the fields rather than writing all the fields out so awfully.

Comment: Please create a minimal example that doesn't include so much incidental complexity that is not relevant to the question you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a test for your case, I created a dummy class that resembles yours:

```
public static class Something{
        private String name;
        private Integer sum;
        private boolean  checker;

        public Something(String name, Integer sum, boolean checker) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sum = sum;
            this.checker = checker;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public boolean isChecker() {
            return checker;
        }

        public Integer getSum() {
            return sum;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }

            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }

            Something something = (Something) o;

            return new EqualsBuilder().append(getName(), something.getName()).append(getSum(), something.getSum()).isEquals();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).append(getName()).append(getSum()).toHashCode();
        }
    }
```

And then I did this little test

```
List<Something> items = Arrays.asList(new Something("name", 10, false), new Something("name", 14, true), new Something("name", 11, false),
           new Something("name", 11, false), new Something("noName", 12, false));

final Map<Something, Integer> somethingToSumOrLastElement =
  items.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(), // first we collect all your related items into a list
                (list) -> { //this collector allow us to have a finisher, Function<List<Something>, Object>, let's define it
                    final List<Integer> integerStream = list.stream().map(Something::getSum).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    if (list.stream().allMatch(Something::isChecker)) { // we check for the method you want to check
                      //you have to change this depending on required logic
                      //for this case if that's true for every element in the list, we do the reduce by summing
                       return integerStream.stream().reduce(0, (sum, next) -> sum + next);
                    }
                    //if not, we just get the last element of that list
                    return integerStream.stream().reduce(0, (sum, next) -> next);
      })));
```

I think this is ok, but maybe someone has a better idea on how to handle your issue.
Ping me if you need clarification :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @xiumeteo. Your code helped. Really brilliant solution. 

Just one last question. Instead of map of Something as key and list of Sum as value, is it possible to have list of Something with correct sum(either sum or last value) set on Something directly. I now have to loop through map and create another list and set value in key.

Comment: That sound werid given your problem. But of course you can, in the finisher function all you have to do is to reduce in terms of "Something", instead of in terms of Integer. And then just grab the values of the Map.

Comment: If you statically import those methods from `Collectors` it will be more readable.